# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that returns statistics of data. So, if a file contains number of bedrooms, number of students in the local area, I want to create a dictionary with minimum, maximum, and so other statistics as keys and values. I have created the following function. But ended up getting error:

```
def statistics(data):
    stat={}
    stat('minimum')=data.min()
    stat("maximum")=data.max()
    stat("mean")=data.mean()
    stat("median")=data.median()
    stat("std")=data.std()
    return stat
room_stat=statistics(data['RM'])
print room_stat
```

Error:

```
stat('minimum')=data.min()
    SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: `stat['minimum']` not `stat('minimum')`

Comment: I have resolved. It's stupid. Adding to a dictionary is: `stat['minimum']=data.min()`              Not                          `stat('minimum')=data.min()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an indentation problem:

```
def statistics(data):
    stat={}
    stat('minimum')=data.min()
    stat("maximum")=data.max()
    stat("mean")=data.mean()
    stat("median")=data.median()
    stat("std")=data.std()
    return stat

room_stat=statistics(data['RM'])
print room_stat
```

And an assignation problem:

```
def statistics(data):
    stat={}
    stat['minimum']=data.min()
    stat["maximum"]=data.max()
    stat["mean"]=data.mean()
    stat["median"]=data.median()
    stat["std"]=data.std()
    return stat

room_stat=statistics(data['RM'])
print room_stat
```

Comment: It's my editing problem in stack overflow. If it is a indentation problem, the error will be:
`stat['minimum']=data.min()
                              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: Read my answer, you have two problem. I answer both

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning values to dictionary properly, use

```
def statistics(data):
    stat={}
    stat['minimum']=data.min()
    stat["maximum"]=data.max()
    stat["mean"]=data.mean()
    stat["median"]=data.median()
    stat["std"]=data.std()
    return stat
room_stat=statistics(data['RM'])
print room_stat
```

Hope it will help.Happy Coding !

Answer (score 1):

```
stat={}
```

stat is defined as a dictionary. So when you are doing stat('minimum') python is considering it as function call.
Change to

```
stat['minimum']=data.min()
stat["maximum"]=data.max()
stat["mean"]=data.mean()
stat["median"]=data.median()
stat["std"]=data.std()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. Adding to a dictionary is: `stat['minimum']=data.min()`              Not                          `stat('minimum')=data.min()`